# Including HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've to use loads of `text`in javascript as `templates`. Its too bad (I know).
However, when I fetch the results through Ajax/PHP/JSON, it was elegant but made the fetching of results a little slow. I was displaying the matter in a popup.
So again I'm back to templates.
My question is: 
"Is there any tool that can automatically parse the HTML code into javascript".

Example:
In `HTML`, the following code

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Round</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab3">Rules</a></li>
</ul>
```

becomes in javascript as:

```
'<ul class="tabs">'+
    '<li><a href="#" name="#tab1">Introduction</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Round</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="#" name="#tab3">Rules</a></li>'+
'</ul>'+
```

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Somewhat related: look at the source of Facebook, and you will see that they include what appear to be templates inside `<code>` elements. Presumably this is so they don't have to include the HTML as a string inside their scripts, nor do they need to request it from the server.

Comment: @TimMedora: Can you please provide me with a tutorial of how to load hidden `div` content through jQuery/javascript?

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: What's bad about using `<script>` tags?  If you can't precompile your templates (really the optimal thing, I think), then `<script>` tags with a non-JavaScript "type" are fine.

Comment: After looking at different template solutions, EJS was easily the best as it didn't require you to learn anything more than JavaScript syntax. EJS allows remote loading of content as well as through local script tags with type=text/html. Your point about script is not understood as its not actually script when using type=text/html and is ignored by the browser in terms of parsing script or dom.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2E5fH/) of how to do it using hidden `<code>` elements. Facebook does this extensively.

HTML:

```
<div>here is some normal content</div>
<code class="template" id="template1"> 
  <div>this is a template</div>
</code>

<div id="renderedTemplate"></div>
```

Script:

```
var template = $("#template1").html();
var templateOutput = $("#renderedTemplate");

for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    templateOutput.append(template);  
}
```

CSS:

```
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

However, since you aren't Facebook, make your life easier and use something like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) as @Shmiddty suggested. It uses a similar approach, but adds powerful templating capabilities into the mix, rather than verbatim string insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Put you content in an hidden div and load it with .html() method of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button>Show it</button>
<p style="display: none">Hello 2</p>

$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").show("slow");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/show/